# Sitecore 8.1 Auto Publish Does not publish

Tags: sitecore, publish

Hello Sitecore masters,

I have an issue with auto publish and I am not able to figure it out.

So I create some items in Sitecore with an external page and they should have a specific publish / unpublish date

So I have a publish / unpublish value, I have setup the Agent but the publish does not work and I don't know how to debug it. I check the logs and it says that items were skipped. I assume it's about my items

This how it looks in sitecore.config

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:10">
<param desc="source database">master</param>
<param desc="target database">web</param>
<param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
<param desc="languages">nb, en</param>
</agent>
```

I have also changed this:

```
<scheduling>
<!-- Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute -->
<frequency>00:00:10</frequency>
```

**The funny / strange thing is that if I publish manually from sitecore, Unpublish will work. The publish doesn't.**

Any hint will be appreciated.

Other informations:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Smart` publishing mode, instead of `Incremental`. Incremental publishing publishes all the items in the publishing queue, which is the list of items known to have been modified.

Get more info about publishing types [here](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/contentreference-a4.pdf)

Comment: I've tried all of them. I think it's something related with the language because, now I've done something - I don't know what - and the item is published, but when I check the web database there is no version. I have 2 languages and English - 0 versions | Norwegian - 0 Version. In master I have 1 Norvegian version

Comment: Sounds expected, if an item doesn't have publishable versions. The behaviour is controlled by Publishing.PublishEmptyItems setting.

Comment: But you see in the screenshots that there are Publishable versions.

Comment: Try changing the language parameter to something like nb-NO, instead of nb. Another good idea is to set <traceToLog>true</traceToLog> in the publishItem pipeline. Then inspect Sitecore log files, publishing will log down more info that may be helpful in troubleshooting.